# how to restore file from mercurial .hg/store/data/

Tags: file, mercurial

I had a file main.py that was committed to mercurial but then accidentally reverted and deleted.

I notice a binary file exists .hg/store/data/main.py.i
Is it possible to restore the original file from this?

Comment: You can only get into trouble by going inside `.hg/store`.  If you're working from the command line instead of a GUI tool like TortoiseHg (which I personally vastly prefer) I would suggest running `hg serve` and going to http://localhost:8000 and browsing your repository that way, it's a much nicer way to explore your codebase than the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, as I said on the mailing list, it is not possible to undo a deletion or revertion like that.

The `-C` option to the `hg update command` says specifically:

```
options:

 -C --clean      discard uncommitted changes (no backup)
 -c --check      update across branches if no uncommitted changes
 -d --date DATE  tipmost revision matching date
 -r --rev REV    revision
    --mq         operate on patch repository
```

So the changes to that file is lost.

What you *can* do is get the file out from a specific revision, but it sounds to me as you had uncommitted changes to the file and the changes and/or file was completely deleted.

Comment: yes unfortunately there is no revision to go back to. Does the main.py.i file contain anything useful?

Comment: If the file was tracked by Mercurial, why isn't there a revision to go back to? Had you added it but not committed it?

Answer (score 2):

You can restore any version of a file with `hg revert -r <revision-where-the-file-existed> file.name`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the file was maintained in another head:

```
hg heads
hg merge -r N
```